# How to remove part of a mesh object

Tags: edit-mode

As part of my 'model' of a concrete apron for the top of a dock I have also created the 'gutter' using the mesh object for the apron (rather than create using single vertice and extrude again)  which will be 'dropped' onto the apron creating a 'concrete apron' with a 'concrete gutter' around the edges (see image) below.
In doing so I now need to remove part of that 'gutter' and considered using a boolean modifier. However I just can't get it to work. I added a mesh cube (colored red in the image below) with correct dimensions to 'cover' that part of the 'gutter' mesh object I want to remove and tried 'difference' but don't seem to be able to get it to work. Maybe I am using the wrong 'tool'?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check face orientation? if yes, pls provide blend file

Comment: No I didn't check the face orientation and have never used in unless accidentally. I hope that I have now uploaded the blender file at the 'exchange'

Comment: To find out what you are doing wrong it would be best to see what you've done. You said you've tried _Difference_ - so I guess you used a _Boolean_ modifier, but there is no _Boolean_ modifier on any object in the file. When I use it, set to _Difference_, the red box is cut out of the 'gutter'. So I can't tell what you did wrong.

Comment: @chris Sorry Chris I didn't save the blend file when I encountered the problem and so had to 'recreate it' and as I though I wasn't using the correct 'tool' didn't bother selecting the boolean modifier.          I have now worked out that I am selecting the wrong mesh before adding the boolean modifier.  I now have it working.  I have only ever used the boolean modifier once before and fell into the same trap (selecting incorrect mesh to add to). Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is what you are looking for:

[image]

use this boolean modifier:

[image]

don't forget to choose an object  - in your uploaded file no object was chosen so Blender cannot execute the boolean modifier.

Also make sure that the cutter is hidden - else you cannot "see" the cut.

And...the boolean modifier is on cube.001 ...you added yours to the wrong object - if i understood you right.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I wanted to achieve AND had achieved before you posted. I must have described it incorrectly but I achieved exactly what you show.  Thanks again for your assistance.